# Ripping PS2 game disks

Tags: ps2, pcsx2

I have an old PS2 slim (77001 series) which no longer works - laser and or motor problem - so I tried working with the PCSX2 emulator.  The emulator installs and for the most part I can read disks inserted into my DVD drive on the host computer.  I was hoping to rip the disks to the hard drive in order to make the emulator more portable, but I find that I cannot read some disks.

A few disks rip fine, but some fail with what appears to be a bad sector error.  Long ago game vendors would include bad sectors on disks to prevent copying, so I'm guessing this is the same thing, but I have no idea of that was even used for PS2 game disks.

Also, the black surface disks will no read in my USB DVD reader.  Is it possible to read these with a standard DVD reader or are the proprietary?

Comment: What program are you using to rip the discs? Some programs out there might have an error checking and correction option that might help. Also, what is the model of your CD/DVD/BD drive?

Comment: I'm using K3B on Fedora.  As for the DVD drive, it is an LG, usb drive - not particularly spophisticated.